# Initial Initialization Organization

Tags: android, initialization

So I'm new to android and a problem or more of an annoyance is my oncreate method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone_inputscreen);

    presetTypeLbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presetTypeLbl);

    calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
    calcBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    distanceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distanceSpinner);
    distanceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);
    areaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    genderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genderSpinner);
    genderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    distanceSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.distanceType));
    areaSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.areaType));
    genderSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.genderType));

    shoeSizeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shoeSizeInput);
    shoeSizeInput.setText("10");

    distanceInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distanceInput);
    distanceInput.setText("0");

    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    menu.setFadeEnabled(false);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.phone_presetscreen);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int width = display.getWidth();
    menu.setBehindOffset(width - 255);

    exv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    ExListViewAdapter exAdapter = new ExListViewAdapter(this, this);
    exv.setAdapter(exAdapter);

}
```

As you can see it a lot of thing just being initialized in the on create method and i find that very... messy. I thought of putting it in a seperate method like so

```
public void initializeInputScreen() {
    presetTypeLbl = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.presetTypeLbl);

    calcBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calcBtn);
    calcBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    distanceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.distanceSpinner);
    distanceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    areaSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.areaSpinner);
    areaSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    genderSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.genderSpinner);
    genderSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    distanceSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.distanceType));
    areaSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.areaType));
    genderSpinner.setAdapter(createSimpleAdapter(R.array.genderType));

    shoeSizeInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.shoeSizeInput);
    shoeSizeInput.setText("10");

    distanceInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.distanceInput);
    distanceInput.setText("0");

    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.RIGHT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_NONE);
    menu.setFadeEnabled(false);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.phone_presetscreen);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    int width = display.getWidth();
    menu.setBehindOffset(width - 255);

    exv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
    ExListViewAdapter exAdapter = new ExListViewAdapter(this, this);
    exv.setAdapter(exAdapter);
}
```

and then i can just call it by

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.phone_inputscreen);
    initializeInputScreen();

}
```

I would like to know how other programmers initialize a multitude of things at once and whats an easier way if there is one.

Comment: It depends on programmer.. if he like his program to be more readable he will do like your second implementation. I also do the same... initialization and listeners are separated by methods and I call them into oncreate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine. Try and define things as much as possible in XML. For example, setting the `EditText` text, you don't need to do that in code.

You could even break down the setup process into further chunks like `setupMenu()` or `initializeList()`.

I try and do this as much as possible - the benefit is **readability.**

Have a read of [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) - some of the things are a bit overkill but I try and apply them to Android development as well.